# What is the Lagranian correponding to this Hamiltonian?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, hamiltonian-formalism

The Hamiltonian is $$H=\vec{S}\cdot\vec{B},$$where $\vec{S}$ is spin, and $\vec{B}$ is external magnetic field. My question is what is the corresponding Lagranian?

Answer (score -2):

What is your canonical variable, and what is it's canonical momentum?  Once you know that, just invert the Legendre transform.

Comment: I know how to do the Legendre transform. But once you regard S as canonical momentum, you will get 0 as the corresponding Lagranian.

Comment: @ShannonLiu - if this is a hamiltonian representing the self-force of a bunch of spins, aren't you missing a term?